# Why my model's Date property is not shown in this input field?

Tags: angularjs

My model has a Date type property (vm.reportSchedule.StartSchedule) set to today.

I need to format the date for display in this input field of type text.

I am using this directive from Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/R16IPQ?p=preview

> I added a reference to moment.js and using required HTML syntax:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.StartSchedule" 
       mo-date-input="MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A" readonly required />
```

**The date is not shown in this field for some reason.**

**BTW, in that plunker, if you get rid of ng-repeat, it stoppes working, I dont understand why.**

No JS errors, date format string is correct.

[image]

**The directive I copied from the Plunker** (no need to check, I just copied it from that Plunker example):

It works just fine in Plunker.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is moment.js referenced in a script tag in your `index.html` file? Did you restart your development server after adding these files?

Comment: I wrote in my post that I added moment.js, no? What development server are you talking about?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: Did you see a link to Plunker code? The question is mainly about it, I want to use. Whhy removing ng-repeat, it stopes working? Do you know?

Comment: The plunk doesn't exist: "Error loading plunk R16IPQ: Not Found"